# How can I make the checkboxes keep their option?

Tags: wordpress, checkbox, radio-button, themes

I have built a WP theme with an options panel, and I have a small issue.

If you are looking at the code below, I have two checkboxes (type="radio")
The problem is that these checkboxes are not keeping their option after I refresh the options page, but they are added to the database because I see the changes in front-end.

```
public static function optionsframework_slider_function($id,$std,$oldorder,$order,$int){

    $data = get_option(OPTIONS);
    
    $slider = '';
    $slide = array();
    $slide = $data[$id];
    
    if (isset($slide[$oldorder])) { $val = $slide[$oldorder]; } else {$val = $std;}
    
    //initialize all vars
    $slidevars = array('type', 'title', 'desc', 'content');
    
    foreach ($slidevars as $slidevar) {
        if (!isset($val[$slidevar])) {
            $val[$slidevar] = '';
        }
    }
    
    //begin slider interface    
    if (!empty($val['title'])) {
        $slider .= '<li><div class="slide_header"><strong>'.stripslashes($val['title']).'</strong>';
    } else {
        $slider .= '<li><div class="slide_header"><strong>Slide '.$order.'</strong>';
    }
    
    $slider .= '<input type="hidden" class="slide pixy-input order" name="'. $id .'['.$order.'][order]" id="'. $id.'_'.$order .'_slide_order" value="'.$order.'" />';

    $slider .= '<a class="slide_edit_button" href="#">Edit</a></div>';
    
    $slider .= '<div class="slide_body">';
    
    $slider .= '<label>Slide Type</label>';
    $slider .= '
    <div class="slide pixy-checkbox">
    <input class="slide pixy-input pixy-slider-type" name="'. $id .'['.$order.'][type]" type="radio" value="html"><div>HTML Slide</div>
    <input class="slide pixy-input pixy-slider-type" name="'. $id .'['.$order.'][type]" type="radio" value="video"><div>Video/ Image Wide Slide</div>
    </div>
    ';
    
    
    $slider .= '<label>Slide Title</label>';
    $slider .= '<input class="slide pixy-input pixy-slider-title" name="'. $id .'['.$order.'][title]" id="'. $id .'_'.$order .'_slide_title" value="'. stripslashes($val['title']) .'" />';
    
    $slider .= '<label>Slide Description</label>';
    $slider .= '<input class="slide pixy-input" name="'. $id .'['.$order.'][desc]" id="'. $id .'_'.$order .'_slide_desc" value="'. $val['desc'] .'" />';
    
    $slider .= '<label>Slide Content</label>';
    $slider .= '<textarea class="slide pixy-input" name="'. $id .'['.$order.'][content]" id="'. $id .'_'.$order .'_slide_content" cols="8" rows="8">'.stripslashes($val['content']).'</textarea>';

    $slider .= '<a class="slide_delete_button" href="#">Delete</a>';
    $slider .= '<div class="clear"></div>' . "\n";

    $slider .= '</div>';
    $slider .= '</li>';

    return $slider;
}
```

The code for checkboxes is (*it can be found in the code above):

```
$slider .= '<label>Slide Type</label>';
        $slider .= '
        <div class="slide pixy-checkbox">
        <input class="slide pixy-input pixy-slider-type" name="'. $id .'['.$order.'][type]" type="radio" value="html"><div>HTML Slide</div>
        <input class="slide pixy-input pixy-slider-type" name="'. $id .'['.$order.'][type]" type="radio" value="video"><div>Video/ Image Wide Slide</div>
        </div>
        ';
```

Here is the code that prints the slider in the frontend:

```
<?php
            $slides = $data['pixy_pixyGallery_slider'];
            if($slides) {
                foreach ($slides as $slide) {
                    echo '<li data-type="'.$slide['type'].'" data-title="'.$slide['title'].'" data-caption="'.$slide['desc'].'">';
                    echo do_shortcode( $slide['content'] );
                    echo '</li>';
               }
            }
            ?>
```

Comment: Why don't you test the value of your option and print `checked="yes"` if necessary ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like?

```
$slider .= '<label>Slide Type</label>';
$slider .= '<div class="slide pixy-checkbox">';

$slider .= '<input class="slide pixy-input pixy-slider-type" name="'. $id .'['.$order.'][type]" type="radio" value="html"';
if($order=='html'){ $slider .= 'checked="checked">'; }else{ $slider .= '>' }
$slider .="<div>HTML Slide</div>";

$slider .= '<input class="slide pixy-input pixy-slider-type" name="'. $id .'['.$order.'][type]" type="radio" value="video"';
if($order=='video'){ $slider .= 'checked="checked">'; }else{ $slider .= '>' }
$slider .= '<div>Video/ Image Wide Slide</div>';
$slider .= '</div>';
```

this depends on the value of $order to see if its set to a preset value?
you need to know this value in-order to check it against!

or set it to check the option value(if you have set 1!)? which ever is easier.

Marty

Comment: Thank you Marty, I am still learning PHP so I might not understand you too well. I don't think the $order has a preset value, because the slides are movable (*sortable). I have tried your code and it does not work. Maybe I should add something on $slidevars = array('type', 'title', 'desc', 'content');  ??

Comment: I have also added the code that prints the slider on the frontend.

Comment: when you save your options, this is stored in the options table for wordpress, what to do is do a print out of all your options.. $options  = get_option('YourOptionName'); print_r($options); then take a look, find the option name for your radio buttons? which ever name and value pair you used to store that value, you will have to do a check with the above code to find that name, value pair, once you find it, just alter the above code to suit the names, then the check will go something like, if($youroptionname=='html') or video, then you can process the checked="checked"..